# How do I put all of my user input from a for loop into an array (or variable)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble with my code :( I am trying to get the answer from my for loop and put it in an array(or variable). This is my code

```
Scanner szKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner iKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String szFavouriteSubjects = null;
int iSubject;

System.out.print("How many of your GCSE subjects do you enjoy? ");
iSubject = iKeyboard.nextInt();

for(int i=1; i<=iSubject; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter subject " + i + ": ");
    szFavouriteSubjects = szKeyboard.nextLine();
}

System.out.println(szFavouriteSubjects);
```

This is the output

How many of your GCSE subjects do you enjoy? 4

Enter subject 1: English

Enter subject 2: Maths

Enter subject 3: French

Enter subject 4: German

German

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having?

Comment: You'd have to start by creating an array.

Comment: Basically, I have 4 subjects. I am entering which subjects I enjoy but when I store them, one of them print out as shown above

Comment: How do I create an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an array with the size you attain and set each element :

```
Scanner szKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner iKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How many of your GCSE subjects do you enjoy? ");
int iSubject = iKeyboard.nextInt();

String[] subjectArr = new String[iSubject];

for(int i=1; i<=iSubject; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter subject " + i + ": ");
    subjectArr[i-1] = szKeyboard.nextLine();
}

for(String subject : subjectArr)
{
    System.out.println("Subject yadayada: " + subject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the results in a list:

```
Scanner szKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner iKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
int iSubject;

System.out.print("How many of your GCSE subjects do you enjoy? ");
iSubject = iKeyboard.nextInt();

for(int i=1; i<=iSubject; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Enter subject " + i + ": ");
    results.add(szKeyboard.nextLine());
}

System.out.println(results);
```

Comment: Do you know how to put it in a array?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm bothering you but thank you for this but I need to  put this into this output
How many of your GCSE subjects do you enjoy? 3
Enter subject 1: Computer Science
Enter subject 2: Maths
Enter subject 3: Art
You enjoy following subjects:
1. Art
2. Computer Science
3. Maths"

Comment: How do I do that